# Who actually lives in Tomorrowland?

Tags: tomorrowland

This is going to be pretty much all spoilers, but here we go.

The premise of Tomorrowland is that some of the world's brightest minds have found another dimension, and intend to use it as an intellectual utopia, to further their work for better humanity.

They plan to introduce potential residents to the idea by showing them an illusion of the ideal Tomorrowland, a trailer for their utopia.

But the badges which carry these trailers are distributed by artificial humans, they aren't really people. When we actually see the present day Tomorrowland, there's definitely robots (obvious, metal ones) and only one person living there.

So my question is this, how many human beings actually went to Tomorrowland? We know about the four scientists who initially founded it, and George Clooney (Frank Walker) and Hugh Laurie (Nix). The rest of the residents might have been artificial, or an illusion.

Is there a source on this?

I'm talking about prior to the ending of the film.

Comment: This film really irked me. The plan was to create a perfect utopian society on Earth by siphoning off the greatest thinkers to another world, then the people who live in Tomorrowland decide that the Earth is doomed so they...erm...decide to help matters along by causing an apocalype? Huh?

Comment: I think the idea was that without distraction, and with a like minded community to support them, they could progress much quicker and humanity would benefit. It's not completely clear about what went wrong.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How/why did Tomorrowland depopulate?](http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/41520/how-why-did-tomorrowland-depopulate)

Comment: I've VTC as a dupe. I'm pretty sure there isn't a canon number on how many people are left in Tomorrowland, just that it's heavily depopulated due to the number of people who've left in disgust.

Comment: Tom Cruise?? You mean George Clooney.

Comment: @bobbyalex you can edit the question if it's wrong

Comment: @Richard it's not quite a duplicate, I'm also asking if there was more than 6 there at all.